# How to determine the order of a reaction with not a commensurate rate equation

Tags: kinetics

As an example of such reactions let's take decomposition of $\ce{N2O}$ which I got the equation from a textbook :

$\ce{N2O = N2 + 1/2 O2}$

with the rate equation of $$-r_{\ce{N2O}}=\frac{k_1[\ce{N2O}]^2}{1+k_2[\ce{N2O}]}$$

So how do we determine the overall order of reaction or order of reaction with respect to a reactant/product ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest with you, the term "order of reaction" is not an exact term. If I want to pull out the rigorous kinetician out of the closet, I'd say that only elementary reactions have orders, and we have first or second (or zero or maybe third) order reactions only, and they are obvious to spot.

What you have is not an elemental reaction, but an overall - somewhat empirical - net reaction rate for a complex mechanism. I personally do not like to talk about orders of non-elementary reactions, but some authors do this. In this context, I'd say your reaction is first order in $\ce{N_2O}$, simply because you have concentration squared divided by *approximately* concentration. Note that if $\ce{[N_2O]}$ is sufficiently large (so the $1$ in the denominator is negligible), the equation becomes $-r =\ce{\frac{k_1 [N_2O]^2}{k_2 [N_2O]} = k' [N_2O]}$, so in high concentration limit the unimolecular approximation becomes exact.

Comment: Also, in the case of sufficiently small concentrations of $N_2O$, we could approximate the rate law to be 2nd order overall.